# FabricJS: Issue in the selection of shapes angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, fabricjs, fabricjs2

Currently, I'm working on fabricjs where I'm drawing a different shape. When I do so the shapes are drawn perfectly fine but when I switch to selection mode I'm not able to select the shape. 
But, when I draw a lot of shapes and select them all together, I'm able to select all of them and later I'm able to individually select shapes which weren't happening before.

> my code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a5tghd

the code that I referred to in order to make this progress

> reference code: [Fabric js : fabric js drawing mode and selection mode options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48662607/fabric-js-fabric-js-drawing-mode-and-selection-mode-options/48663975#48663975)

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you press on hand option you need to parse all the objects from canvas and call `setCoords`function [image]

Comment: This is working like a charm. thanks. can you also explain to me why should I do this?

Comment: Here is the explenation:https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/wiki/When-to-call-setCoords

Comment: Is it possible to add a button over the selected object so that the user can delete the object if needed?

Comment: Yes you can. Here is an example: http://fabricjs.com/interaction-with-objects-outside-canvas